# реализация списковой сборки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, как записать эту часть кода в виде списковой сборки применив функцию not any()

```
except Empty:
            for ticker in tickers:
                if not ticker.is_alive():
                    break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  not all(ticker.is_alive() for ticker in tickers)
```

Ну или без `not` тоже самое, непонятно дальше вы проверяете результат вообще или нет.

Данная конструкция будет перебирать элементы цикла, пока не найдёт элемент, который вернёт `False`.